# I's it possible to mount a remote filesystem in non-rooted Android (like an SD card)?

Tags: android, fuse

I have a DIY NAS and would like to stream files/media from it to various Android powered devices (like a phone or Android TV) such that apps like VLC can browse/stream the remote contents like they were mounted locally.

The advantage of this is it doesn't require transcoding (like Plex) and puts the responsibility of decoding on the client.

I have previously used SMB but it's not safe exposed to the internet.

Another alternative I tried was using ssh on Android via termux to forward the smb port so VLC could access the files.

This worked but it's not practical given the excessive setup required.

Comment: If the internet connection of the NAS is good enough (upstream+downstream) then I would recommend to install a VPN system like Wireguard. No Termux fiddling required on Android side and the Wireguard server requires very little CPU on NAS side (compared to other VPNs).